# Tag rename request: [hana-saku-iroha] to [hanasaku-iroha]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retagging

[hana-saku-iroha](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hana-saku-iroha) should be changed to [hanasaku-iroha](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hanasaku-iroha), since that is how it is officially localized - see, for example, [the English-language box set](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/releases.php?id=22901) (or [on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00B1UYJ14)).